# Can I create well-typed dictionaries from XML data when the dictionaries have different types?

Tags: c#, xml, types, xml-deserialization

I'm looking to transform the following XML information into a collection of dictionaries. Each `<Transform>` describes a dictionary, and each `<Map>` describes a key-value pair. This is intended to be deserialized at runtime, so solutions that make serialization difficult aren't out of the question.

```
<Config>
  <Transform Input="System.String" Output="System.Boolean">
    <Map Input="Yes" Output="true"></Map>
    <Map Input="No" Output="false"></Map>
  </Transform>
  <Transform Input="System.String" Output="System.Int32">
    <Map Input="Category1" Output="1"></Map>
    <Map Input="Category2" Output="2"></Map>
    <Map Input="Category3" Output="3"></Map>
    <Map Input="Category4" Output="4"></Map>
  </Transform>
</Config>
```

Here's my first stab at making types for these to be deserialized into. The data is properly deserialized into these classes, so the only remaining step is converting it into a dictionary.

```
    [XmlRoot]
    public class Config
    {
        [XmlElement("Transform")]
        public List<Transform> Transforms { get; set; }
    }

    public class Transform
    {
        [XmlIgnore]
        private Type inputType { get; set; }

        [XmlIgnore]
        private Type outputType { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Input {
            get { return inputType.AssemblyQualifiedName; }
            set
            {
                inputType = Type.GetType(value, true);
            }
        }

        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Output
        {
            get { return outputType.AssemblyQualifiedName; }
            set
            {
                outputType = Type.GetType(value, true);
            }
        }

        [XmlElement("Map")]
        public List<Map> Mappings { get; set; }
    }

    public class Map
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Input { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Output { get; set; }
    }
```

My initial strategy was to find a way to use the System.Type objects to add a function to the transform class that would return the appropriate dictionary, but the best I could learn how to do was return a `Dictionary<object, object>`.

- Maybe there's some way to make the `Transform` class generic?
- Maybe `Dictionary<T, U>` isn't the right target, but some other structure would fit better? (The consumer of these dictionaries would expect `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, bool>>` for the first transform)

EDIT: The end goal would be to have a dictionary of `<string, bool>` for the first transform in the XML and a dictionary of `<string, int>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<Type, List<KeyValuePair<string, Boolean>>>> dict = doc.Descendants("Transform")
                .GroupBy(x => Type.GetType((string)x.Attribute("Input")), y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.GroupBy(a => Type.GetType((string)a.Attribute("Output")), b => b.Elements("Map").Select(c => new KeyValuePair<string, Boolean>((string)c.Attribute("Input"), (string)c.Attribute("Output") == "true" ? true : false)).ToList())
                    .ToDictionary(a => a.Key, b => b.FirstOrDefault()));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This gets me a set of <string, string> pairs but my end goal is to get <string, bool> pairs for the first transform and <string, int> pairs for the second. My bad for not making that more clear; I'll edit the question to make that more explicit.